# How to access artifacts in Kubeflow runtime?

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I would like to access `mlpipeline-metrics` content from another component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch metrics from a run:

```
client = kfp.Client(host=host)
client.get_run(run_id).run.metrics
```